# One CosmosDB state storage for many bots?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using my own state storage for my bot, hosted over Azure CosmosDB.

Currently, i'm working on a similar bot for a different customer, which is going to be a new botframework bot.

I was wondering if it's safe to use the same state storage?
Do I need to add certain information for each document?

Comment: Why this should not be safe. It depends on how to manage the storage.

Comment: @OmG I do not manage my storage, Botframework does.
There might be an issue with a conflict of IDs and this is my main concern.

Comment: You could do this, but it wouldn't be the recommended way.  individual state stores would be recommended

Comment: What do you mean by "same state storage?" Same collection? Same database account? Separate collections have completely independent id's. But... we know nothing about how your bots are storing id's. Or the storage requirements. So, as written, this is a fairly broad question with no definitive way to answer it.

Comment: @JasonSowers - why isn't it the recommended way? And *what* isn't recommended: same Cosmos DB account? Same collection? And why would individual state stores be recommended? I don't understand the basis of your comment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I cannot provide a full answer for node, but could for C#. You may be able to port that over to Node. Not really sure if that works for you or not so let me know and maybe I can answer this in a C# based question.  It basically boils down to the key used to retrieve data and it not containing the Bot ID, therefore conversation IDs and user IDs could possibly overlap.